# "お会いできる日を楽しみにしています"

Tags: translation

I met a Japanese couple last night who didn't speak English but my Japanese is terrible. I plan to write them a brief email just to thank them for their hospitality.

Does お会いできる日を楽しみにしています mean "It'd be nice to be able to meet you"? If it won't be the first meeting but that it'd just be good to meet the person again, is "お会いできる日を楽しみにしています" still appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

お会いできる日を楽しみにしています is indeed a very common expression with many variants, e.g. お会いするのを楽しみにしています, お会いしたい, etc.

Even in English I would say something like "It'd be nice to be able to meet you *again*" for a second meeting. In fact, in the [BCCWJ](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1086/1628) (Japanese corpus) more than 10% of the occurrences of お会い use また before it (as in またお会いしましょう or またいつかお会いできるといいね etc.):

```
お会い          964 results
また ... お会い  99 results
```

So, in your situation I'd say that

> またお会いできる日を楽しみにしています

would be spot on.

Answer (score 2):

お会いできる日を楽しみにしています is the same with "I'm looking forward to seeing you again," and is polite as well as appropriate as a closing of a letter.

You can also add 'また (again)' or 'また[近々]{ちかぢか}(soon again)' to お会いできる日を楽しみにしています so that you may convey your desire to meet the receiver keenly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special word for reuniting: 再会(さいかい）.
I believe when using this word some significant amount of time should or will be anticipated to have passed in-between meetings.
So, if you don't expect to see them in the immediate future you could say:
「〇〇さんとの再会が待ち遠しいです」Where 〇〇さん is their name.

Comment: 再開 of the first line should be read 再会.

Comment: My mistake, I updated it now to be the correct character usage. Thank you for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

You translation is correct, and I believe the same phrase can be used in either situation. However, I was taught to use はじめまして when meeting someone for the first time.